# Using a WrapPanel as the Items Panel for a ListBox with Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm a beginner in WPF. I try to do a project in MMVM WPF.

I show a list of film with IMG and label. My problem is when I select a film I can't open a new window.

I have a form with button Command it's good but when I put a button in listbox.itemTemplate it don't work.

My code is:

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Button Command="{Binding CommandeShowFilm}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}"   Width="220"  Height="326"></Image>
                    </Button>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Titre}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

And my .cs

```
     public ICommand CommandeShowFilm { get; set; }
     //in constructor
     CommandeShowFilm = new RelayCommand(ActionShowFilm);
```

ActionShowFilm is empty.
What's the problem. When I click a button my command is don't work and how can I open a new window with data after the click?

Comment: The Image.InputBindings doesn't seem to make any sense. You have already bound the Button's Command. Besides that, it's unclear what "ActionShowFilm is empty" is supposed to mean. And what has all that got to do with the WrapPanel? Does it work with some other ItemsPanel?

Comment: Why is ActionShowFilm empty if you want to display a window when the Button is clicked? And what does "don't work" actually mean? What happens and what are you expect to happen when the Button is clicked?

Comment: it's empty because i don't implement. When I click it don't pass in my relay command . I try to pass in my relay command yet..